# For loop to merge df

Tags: r

I am hoping to merge a number of data frames, one is called A, the other is called Comments_[[i]], and i ranges from 1 to 36. The name of the common column is called "Item.i.Q3", again i ranges from 1 to 36.

without a loop l I will do the following 36 times (changing i to a number ranged from 1 to 36) :

`outcome <- merge(A , Comments_[[i]], by="Item.i.Q3", all= TRUE)`

Was wondering if I can build a loop so I don't have to do it 36 times? Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Hm i might be missing something from that page you linked me, but I guess my question is I do not want to repeat the merge process 36 times, and so was hoping to see if I can build a loop to do the work. :)

Comment: Syl, to reiterate a couple points here, *we* are missing something here: reproducibility. As much as it sounds like we want everything handed to us, that's far from the truth: there are several components to problems like this that, lacking concrete samples, are left to our imagination or interpretation. While I suspect `Reduce(function(a,b) merge(a,b,by="Item.i.Q3",all.x=TRUE), mget(ls(pattern="Comments_")), init=A)` (very similar to @G.Grothendieck's answer) will work, it's difficult to know for sure without sample data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Construct a character vector of the names, `df_names`,  and define the `merge` function needed, `Merge`. Then use `mget` to get the data fames themselves and use `Reduce` to iterate `Merge` over them.  We assume that the common column to merge on is column number i in A and is 1 in all the other data frames.

```
# test data
i <- 1 # position of column in A to merge on; assume 1 for others
A <- Comments_1 <- Comments_2 <- BOD

df_names <- ls(pattern = "^Comments_")
Merge <- function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 1, all = TRUE)
Reduce(Merge, mget(df_names), cbind(A[i], A[-i]))
```

giving:

```
  Time demand.x demand.y demand
1    1      8.3      8.3    8.3
2    2     10.3     10.3   10.3
3    3     19.0     19.0   19.0
4    4     16.0     16.0   16.0
5    5     15.6     15.6   15.6
6    7     19.8     19.8   19.8
```

Comment: Thanks - but the common columns are named differently in Comments_[[i]] - for Comments_[[1]], the common column is called Item.1.Q3; for Comments_[[2]], the common column is called Item.2.Q3 .. do you think there is a way to get around that please? :)

Comment: Thanks for replying again. I guess it is not in the same position in A, as a will have column Item.1.Q3 all the way to Item.36.Q3  :(

Comment: Have moved comments to answer.  If this still does not reflect what you have then please provide a reproducible example which you should have done in the first place.